# CodeBots 2: Event Driven Design

Tags: king-of-the-hill

Welcome to Code Bots 2!

You've learned your lesson since the last Code Bots.  You've tried to figure out more ways to fit more actions in less lines, and now you finally have it.  You're going to make an event-driven Code Bot.

Your bot must consist of 24 lines.  Each line follows one of the two formats:

```
Condition:Action
```

or

```
Action
```

Your bot also have enough storage to store 5 integers named `A` through `E`.  An integer can store values from 0 to 23.

Each turn, you will execute line `C`, *unless* one of the conditions is true.  If so, then `C` will then contain the line number of the conditional that is true, and then that line will be executed.  At the end of each turn, `C` will be incremented.

There are the available conditions:

1. `Start` is true only on the first turn.  You must have this in your code exactly once
2. `BotAt(N)` is true if there is a bot at the location defined by N
3. `Equals(A,B)` is true if A equals B.  They can be different types, if so, they will not be equal.
4. `Modified(A)` is true if `A` was copied to during the last turn.  `A` must be a variable name, a line, or a condition
5. `Any(C1,C2,...)` is true if any of the conditions are true
6. `None(C1,C2,...)` is true if none of the conditions are true
7. `All(C1,C2,...)` is true if all of the conditions are true
8. `Not(C)` is true if C is false. `C` must be a condition.

Variables can be in one of the following formats.  The first 9 are numerical, and can be be used for whenever N is used in this page.

1. `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`
2. A number from 0 to 23
3. `This` will return the line number it is currently on
4. `Add(N1,N2,...)` will return the sum of all values
5. `Sub(N1,N2)` will return N1 minus N2
6. `Mult(N1,N2,...)` will return the product of all values
7. `Div(N1,N2)` will return N1 divided by N2
8. `Mod(N1,N2)` will return N1 mod N2
9. `OVar(N)` will accept a variable name, and will return the opponent's variable
10. `Line(N)` will return the Nth line in your code
11. `Type(N)` will return the Nth line type in your code (the types are the names of the actions)
12. `Cond(N)` will return condition on the Nth line
13. `CondType(N)` will return the condition type on the Nth line  (the types are the names of the conditions)
14. `OLine(N)` will return the Nth line in your opponent's code
15. `OType(N)` will return the Nth line type in your opponent's code
16. `OCond(N)` will return the condition on the Nth line
17. `OCondType(N)` will return the condition type on the Nth line

`A` and `B` are for your personal use, `C` is used to determine which line to execute in your code, and `D` is used as a direction. Each value of `D` refer to a different square and direction pair.`E` produces a random value each time.  `D` and `E` will be initialized to a random value, otherwise `0`.

The direction used will be `[North,East,South,West][D%4]`.  Your opponent is the bot in the immediate square in that direction.

There are 4 actions available to you:

1. `Move` will move you 1 square forward in the `D`th direction.  If there is a bot there, you will not move.
2. `Copy(A,B)` will copy the variable `A` to `B`.  `B` cannot be a numerical value, except for a variable name.  `A` and `B` cannot be of different types.  Copying a line does not copy the condition.
3. `Flag` does nothing.  **The bot with the most flags in your code will get a point.  The bot with the most points wins.**
4. `If(C,L1,L2)` will perform the line on `L1` if `C` is true, else performs `L2`. `C` is a condition, and `L1` and `L2` must be lines.

## The Big Picture

50 copies of every bot will be placed in the world.  Your goal is to get your flag into as many bots as possible.  For each bot that has more of your flag type than any other flag type, you get a point.

The bots will be placed as follows:

```
B...B...B...B...
..B...B...B...B.
B...B...B...B...
```

There will be 10 games run, and points will be averaged across all of the games, determining who the winner is.

## Side Notes

If multiple conditions apply, then the one that most immedately follows `Start` will be executed

The bots will be closely packed but you will not start neighboring another bot.  (It techincally will be the same format as the last CodeBots)

As this challenge was not posted in the sandbox (to give nobody an advantage), I reserve the right to change small details for fairness, or additional capabilities.  Also, if there is a bug in the CodeBots runner, I will change it, even if a bot depended on that bug for its success.  I am trying to be as *fair* as possible.

Recursive `If` statements will not be executed

If your bot is shorter than 24 lines, the remaining lines will be filled with `Flag`

Remember when copying to your own `C`, that `C` is incremented at the end of your turn.

The CodeBots interpreter can be found [here](https://github.com/thenameipicked/CodeBots2Java).  It includes a .jar file for easy execution.  Simply add your bot to the bots folder

## Scores

1. 893.9    Borg
2. 1.3  LazyLioness
3. 0.9  Defender
4. 0.5  Flagger
5. 0.4  CliqueBot
6. 0.4  Insidious
7. 0.3  Attacker
8. 0.3  Gard
9. 0.3  SingleTarget
10. 0.2 FreezeBot
11. 0.2 Sentinel
12. 0.2 Driveby
13. 0.0 AntiInsidious
14. 0.0 MoveBot
15. 0.0 CliqueBorg
16. 0.0 Calculator
17. 0.0 TestBot
18. 0.0 Imitator

### UPDATE

Lines of code are now rotated when you view your opponent's code.  That means, your opponent's line 1 may be line 14 (or whatever line).  A bot will have a fixed offset which will offset his lines by `X` amount *when viewed by an opponent*.  The opponent's `C` variable will also be offset by the same `X` amount.  `X` will not change within the same game, but it will change from game to game.

Comment: Nathan: Are you able to check out "Lazy Lioness" to see whether the bugs I've reported are legitimate (or if I'm just out to lunch)? No rush. Just making sure you're aware of the submission.

Comment: @COTO Sorry, schools been crazy.  I'll try to get to it tonight.

Comment: The 'All' condition could be made implicit for any comma separated list of conditions. It would make reading the entries a bit easier.

Comment: I think I found your bug. The FuctionParser objects are being used as keys in a HashMap which means you need a proper equals method. This fixes the problem with CliqueBot and likely Lazy Lioness as well. I sent you a pull request.

Comment: @ccarton the HashMap only memoizes the values, it isn't used for testing equality

Comment: HashMaps don't work properly unless the keys have .equals() methods. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351261/do-i-need-to-implement-hashcode-and-equals-methods). This is causing the memoizer to return different objects for the same line text.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/1100158) is a better explanation of reason for the hashcode and equals requirements.

Comment: @ccarton I understand that that is a bug.  However, it does *not* affect the actual program execution.  It simply prevents additional parsing from being done.

Comment: It does affect execution because your Action class also does not have a .equals() method which means it is relying on reference equality. So when the HashMap returns two different Action objects for the same line text those Actions won't evaluate as equal.

Comment: Ah.  Then *that* is the bug.  I know how to fix it.  Thank you.

Comment: @ccarton: That does fix the problem of the spurious interrupts. Unfortunately, Lazy Lioness still does nothing. The conditions seem to be evaluating properly (i.e. green in the right places), and the instruction pointer seems to be at the right location (i.e. blue at the right place), but it's as if the controller is ignoring the instructions. I might have time on the weekend to look into it, but since you're already familiar with the code, maybe you could take another look. It sounds like Nathan is swamped with work.

Comment: Glad I could help. I couldn't tell if that was by design or not. It would theoretically work fine if the memoizer worked properly. Even if you change that, you should still fix the other bug as well.

Comment: @COTO: If I get a chance I'll have a look. It's possible that the lack of an equals method on the Action class is causing some additional issues, as apparently that wasn't by design. Give it another try after Nathan fixes that.

Comment: When will you refresh your scoreboard?

Comment: Ok.  I fixed that bug (and another one dealing with `BotAt()`).  Scoreboard posted.

Comment: @COTO It looks like LazyLioness is working as expected.  Realize that priority of conditions is based off of your `Start` condition, not the first line.

Comment: In my tests, his (LasyLioness') start action is not being executed on the first turn. It only executes if I move the start line to the first position. I think there is a bug in Bot.checkConditions(). Should it not be conditionIsTrue(lineNum)?

Comment: _"`Copy(A,B)` will copy the variable `N` to `M`"_ - Huh?

Comment: @NathanMerrill: I placed the `Start` condition on the last line so that the instructions would have the highest priority on line 1 and descending priority below. I assumed the priority queue "wrapped around" the same way as execution order did. But maybe I'm missing something. I'll have more time to play around with the simulator this coming Sunday.

Comment: What happens if I clone a `Start` condition into a non-`Start` condition?

Comment: @TwiNight the initial position of `Start` is used throughout the simulation

Comment: Hey Nathan, did you see my last comment about a possible bug in Bot.checkConditions()?

Comment: @ccarton sorry, I missed it.  fixed and pushed

Comment: I think there is a problem with the offset code. `OLine(OVar(C))` doesn't reference the correct line. For example, if `C` is 1 and the offset is 5, then `OVar(C)` returns 6 and then `OLine(6)` returns data from line 11. I think you need to be subtracting the offset in one of those cases to get them to line up.

Comment: I think `BotAt` is still bugged. Look at Gard. The `BotAt`s are green at all the wrong places.

Comment: I think the problem with `BotAt` is in the `getShiftY` function. It's ignoring it's parameter and calculating direction from `D`. Looks like maybe it's old code that you meant to delete?

Comment: @ccarton thanks for the help with the bugs.  It's tough to find them all.  They are fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the offset makes porting MindControl impossible (due to the victim unable to correctly reference my own lines), and Borg is doing so well that all my resistance attempts so far are indeed futile.

Comment: Bugs!! `TypeArgument` splits spaces but lines no longer have spaces in CB2

Comment: @TwiNight Ah, good catch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Borg

Converts all other bots into clones of itself. Resistance is futile.

```
Start:Copy(2,A)                               # Cloning will begin at line 2
All(Not(BotAt(D)),Not(Equals(2,A))):Copy(2,A) # Reset A if the opp left before we were done
Not(BotAt(D)):Move
All(Equals(Line(Sub(This,3)),OLine(0)),Equals(Line(Sub(This,2)),OLine(1)),Equals(Line(Sub(This,1)),OLine(2)),Equals(Line(This),OLine(3)),Equals(Line(Add(This,1)),OLine(4)),Equals(Line(Add(This,2)),OLine(5)),Equals(Line(Add(This,3)),OLine(6)),Equals(Line(Add(This,4)),OLine(7)),Equals(Line(Add(This,5)),OLine(8))):Copy(E,D) #  Check if cloning is complete
All(Equals(A,2),Not(Equals(OCond(1),Cond(Add(This,4))))):Copy(Cond(Add(This,4)),OCond(1)) # Copy freeze cond to OLine(1) before cloning starts
All(Equals(A,2),Not(Equals(OLine(1),Line(Add(This,3))))):Copy(Line(Add(This,3)),OLine(1)) # Copy freeze line
Not(Equals(Cond(Add(Sub(This,6),A)),OCond(A))):Copy(Cond(Add(Sub(This,6),A)),OCond(A))    # Copy Cond(A) to OCond(A)
Not(Equals(Line(Add(Sub(This,7),A)),OLine(A))):Copy(Line(Add(Sub(This,7),A)),OLine(A))    # Copy Line(A) to OLine(A)
Equals(A,A):Copy(Add(A,1),A) # Increment A. It will wrap around all 24 lines before the completion check matches
```

*Edit: Small fix to reset A if the opponent moves before I'm done with him. Doesn't seem to affect the score but it makes me feel better.*

*Edit #2: Added a more complete check to ensure the cloning process has completed properly (line 3)*

*Edit #3: Update to handle the new random offsets. The difficulty here was that new clones would have their code located at random offsets which means they don't know the location of their own lines. That means that all references to my own lines must be relative (to `This`). Opponent line numbers can still be absolute since they are random anyway.*

Comment: Hey, can we chat about this bot? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17128/private-chat-between-ccarton-and-nathan

Comment: @Nathan, did you use the latest version of this entry in the most recent run?

Comment: I am amazed that this bot is able to infect other bots so successfully. I'd love to see a rundown of how it works.

Comment: @ccarton no.  I didn't realize it was updated.  Rerunning.

Comment: @Sparr I've added some comments. Hope that makes it easier to follow. I think the bot is so effective because of the exponential effect of the cloning. Each bot it infects goes out and infects others. Also, they will naturally try to repair each other when they take damage.

Comment: I think any bot that beats this will be based on this. I've got an idea for a Borg+RowBot mashup, but it wouldn't beat this by much if at all.

Comment: @Sparr I think you'd be surprised at the snowball effect of the cloning strategy. If you can improve this design by even a small amount it might multiply into a massive lead in overall score. Maybe.

Comment: @ccarton that much is obvious in reverse. I can make tiny changes to this bot that still produce 99% scores alone, but lose to this bot by a large margin.

Answer (score 5):

## Flagger

*Shoot for the moon*

```
Start:Flag
```

And the rest gets auto-filled with flag.

Answer (score 3):

## Calculator

This bot doesn't understand the goal of this challenge, so he decided to calculate some numbers for the enemy.

```
Equals(Mod(OVar(E),5),0):Copy(Add(OVar(A),OVar(B)),OVar(D))
Equals(Mod(OVar(E),5),1):Copy(Sub(OVar(A),OVar(B)),OVar(D))
Equals(Mod(OVar(E),5),2):Copy(Mult(OVar(A),OVar(B)),OVar(D))
Equals(Mod(OVar(E),5),3):Copy(Div(OVar(A),OVar(B)),OVar(D))
Equals(Mod(OVar(E),5),4):Copy(Mod(OVar(A),OVar(B)),OVar(D))
Start:Move
```

Comment: you should put the results into `OVar(D)` not `A`!

Comment: @MegaTom Done ;)

Answer (score 3):

## CliqueBot

```
Flag
Start: Copy(11,B)
Not(Equals(Line(20),Line(21))): If(Equals(Line(21),Line(22)),Line(7),Line(8))
Not(Equals(Line(21),Line(22))): If(Equals(Line(20),Line(21)),Line(9),Line(10))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(11,OVar(B)))): If(Equals(Line(20),OLine(OVar(C))),Line(10),Line(11))
Any(BotAt(D),Equals(E,B)): Copy(Add(D,1),D)
Equals(1,1): Move
Copy(Line(21),Line(20))
Copy(Line(20),Line(21))
Copy(Line(21),Line(22))
If(Equals(Line(20),OLine(Sub(OVar(C),1))),Line(5),Line(12))
Copy(Line(20),OLine(OVar(C)))
Copy(Line(20),OLine(E))
```

Recognizes friends via their `B` value, fills everyone else's lines with flags. Also goes to some length to preserve the integrity of one of its own flags (this part is cute but probably not very useful).

<s>Edit: Unsurprisingly, there appears to be a bug here somewhere, judging by the score.</s>

Suspect that lines are 0-indexed and my code is 1-indexed. Should really have checked that earlier. Added a Flag at the beginning to bump everything up one.

Comment: I think I found the bug in the controller. I sent him a pull request. Until he accepts it, you can try my [fork](https://github.com/ctcarton/CodeBots2Java) if you like and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

## Defender

```
Start:Copy(0,A)
Copy(0,B)
Flag
Flag
All(Modified(Line(2)),Equals(A,0)):Copy(1,A)
Copy(Line(3),Line(2))
Copy(0,A)
Copy(10,C)
All(Modified(Line(3)),Equals(B,0)):Copy(1,B)
Copy(Line(2),Line(3))
Copy(0,B)
BotAt(D):Copy(Line(2),OLine(E))
```

Answer (score 2):

## MoveBot

```
Start:Move
Copy(E,D)
Copy(-1,C)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Copy(23,C)`?

Comment: Negative values are now allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## Attacker

```
Start:Move
BotAt(D):Copy(Line(Add(Mod(E,6),4)),OLine(E))
Any(BotAt(0),BotAt(1),BotAt(2),BotAt(3)):Move
None(BotAt(0),BotAt(1),BotAt(2),BotAt(3)):Copy(E,D)
```

Comment: `BotAt(D):Copy(Line(X),OLine(E))` where line X contains `Equals(1,1):Flag` ... for fun

Comment: @Sieg `Line` copies only the action, not the condition.

Comment: My overpowered tactic :(

Answer (score 2):

## Single Target

```
Start:Move
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OVar(D),D))): Copy(D,OVar(D))
BotAt(D):Copy(Line(E),OLine(E))
Equals(A,A):Move
```

Will hunt you down and fill you with flags!

Comment: The `All` condition needs a `)`

Answer (score 2):

## Insidious

```
Start:Flag           # comments -->                                                                                 # why move when we can fit another flag here?
Equals(E,0):Copy(Add(D,Sub(Mult(2,Mod(E,2)),1)),D)                                                                  # 1/24 chance to turn left or right
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(Sub(OVar(C),1)),Cond(Add(This,4))))):Copy(Cond(Add(This,4)),OCond(Sub(OVar(C),1)))    # Copy the freeze condition
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Sub(OVar(C),1)),Line(Add(This,4))))):Copy(Line(Add(This,4)),OLine(Sub(OVar(C),1)))    # Copy the flag-copying line
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Add(OVar(C),0)),Line(Add(This,Add(4,Mod(E,14))))))):Copy(Line(Add(This,Add(4,Mod(E,14)))),OLine(Add(OVar(C),0))) # copy one of my flags to them
BotAt(D):Copy(Add(D,Sub(Mult(2,Mod(E,2)),1)),D)                                                                     # turn left or right if we've infected our target
Equals(A,A):Move                                                                                                    # move if all else fails, also infection freeze condition
Copy(Line(Add(This,1)),Line(Add(This,Mod(E,22))))                                                                   # infection line 1
Flag                                                                                                                # first of many flags
```

Similar idea to the bot by the same name in the previous contest. Move until I hit another bot, then freeze it into a loop overwriting its own code with my flags. This time the infected bots overwrite random lines instead of sequential lines, making the infection process a little less effective but much faster.

Comment: `Line(4)` can be simplified a bit. `Add(OVar(C),0)` is the same as `OVar(C)` and `Add(This,Add(4,Mod(E,14)))` is the same as `Add(This,4,Mod(E,14))`.

Comment: @MegaTom I did the first unnecessary Add to make the logical parts of the preceding lines line up.
The second one was due to not knowing that Add could take multiple parameters. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Gard

```
Start: Move
BotAt(D):IF(Equals(Line(7),OLine(C)),Line(6),Line(5))
BotAt(Add(D,1)):Copy(Add(D,1),D)
BotAt(Add(D,2)):Copy(Add(D,2),D)
BotAt(Add(D,3)):Copy(Add(D,3),D)
Copy(Line(7),OLine(OVar(C)))
Copy(Cond(7),OCond(Sub(OVar(C),1)))
```

Attacks any robot next to it.

Comment: Your last line cannot copy from a condition to a line.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I was just fixing that...

Comment: `OCon` needs to be `OCond`

Answer (score 1):

## Freeze Bot

```
Start:Move
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(1),Cond(5)))):Copy(Cond(5),OCond(1))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(1),Line(6)))):Copy(Line(6),OLine(1))
All(BotAt(D),Equals(Mod(OVar(A),24),0)):Copy(Add(D,1),D)
BotAt(D):Copy(Line(20),OLine(OVar(A)))
Equals(A,A):Move
Copy(Add(A,1),A)
```

Traps you in a loop Incriminating your own `A` variable, then fills you with flags and moves on to the next victim.

Comment: Line 3: Please replace D+1 with Add(D,1)

Comment: You're assuming that Start is on line zero. Now everyone is incentivized to put their Start on line 2. This is going to lead to a silly escalation/resubmission trend :(

Answer (score 1):

## Imitator

```
Start:Move
BotAt(D):If(OCond(0),OLine(0),Line(2))
If(OCond(1),OLine(1),Line(3))
If(OCond(2),OLine(2),Line(4))
If(OCond(3),OLine(3),Line(5))
If(OCond(4),OLine(4),Line(6))
If(OCond(5),OLine(5),OLine(OVar(C)))
Not(BotAt(D)):If(BotAt(Add(D,1)),Line(8),Line(0))
Copy(Add(D,1),D)
```

Predicts what you would do, then does that.

Comment: Please replace D+1 with Add(D,1)

Comment: Also, you cannot pass in a command as a line.  You either have to pass in a `OLine` or a `Line`

Comment: @NathanMerrill ready to go! (At least I think it is)

Comment: This bot really put my code through some trouble, but that was my fault, not yours.  There are a few bugs, please put `Line` around the `2`, and `Add(D,1)` instead of `D+1`

Answer (score 1):

## Lazy Lioness

Originally just "Lioness", my first submission to the contest earned the title "lazy" by literally doing nothing when introduced into the simulator.

Her lethargy is in fact due to a bug (or possibly my misunderstanding the event model) wherein the conditions in the first three lines (a simple parity check for ensuring that flags are not overwritten) occasionally, inexplicably evaluate `true`, locking leo in a lemniscate loop. Several other conditions (particularly those that rely on the `BotAt()` condition) also evaluate `true` at times when no adjacent bot(s) are present. Finally, `Move` and `Copy` directives are clearly ignored when stepping through the simulator. Since my conditional logic chains are somewhat epic, there's plenty of room for bugs in my code *and* in the simulator. ;)

In any case, I submit Lazy Lioness as a test case for either error diagnosis or simulator debugging, which will hopefully lead to the emergence of not-so-lazy Lioness that I can then simulate and refine as my first bona fide submission to the Bots v2 competition.

**It Does Nothing**

```
All(Not(Equals(Line(18),Line(21))),Equals(Line(21),Line(22))):Copy(Line(21),Line(18))
All(Not(Equals(Line(21),Line(22))),Equals(Line(22),Line(18))):Copy(Line(22),Line(21))
All(Not(Equals(Line(22),Line(18))),Equals(Line(18),Line(21))):Copy(Line(18),Line(22))
All(Any(BotAt(Add(D,1)),BotAt(Add(D,2)),BotAt(Add(D,3))),Not(BotAt(D))):Move
All(Any(All(BotAt(D),BotAt(Add(D,2))),All(BotAt(D),BotAt(Add(D,1))),All(BotAt(Add(D,1)),BotAt(Add(D,2)))),Not(BotAt(Add(D,3)))):Copy(Add(D,3),D)
Any(All(Any(All(BotAt(D),BotAt(Add(D,2))),All(BotAt(D),BotAt(Add(D,3))),All(BotAt(Add(D,2)),BotAt(Add(D,3)))),Not(BotAt(Add(D,1)))),All(BotAt(Add(D,1)),BotAt(D),Any(Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Equals(OLine(2),Line(19))))):Copy(Add(D,1),D)
All(BotAt(Add(D,3)),BotAt(D),Any(Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Equals(OLine(2),Line(19)))):Copy(Add(D,3),D)
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20))),Not(Equals(OLine(2),Line(19)))):Copy(Cond(20),OCond(2))
All(BotAt(D),Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Not(Equals(OLine(3),Line(18)))):Copy(Line(18),OLine(3))
All(BotAt(D),Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Not(Equals(OLine(4),Line(21)))):Copy(Line(21),OLine(4))
All(BotAt(D),Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Not(Equals(OCond(0),Cond(22)))):Copy(Cond(22),OCond(0))
All(BotAt(D),Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Not(Equals(OLine(0),Line(17)))):Copy(Line(17),OLine(0))
All(BotAt(D),Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Not(Equals(OCond(1),Cond(21)))):Copy(Cond(21),OCond(1))
All(BotAt(D),Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Not(Equals(OLine(1),Line(20)))):Copy(Line(20),OLine(1))
All(BotAt(D),Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20)),Not(Equals(OLine(2),Line(19)))):Copy(Line(19),OLine(2))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(2),Cond(20))),Equals(OLine(2),Line(19))):Copy(Add(D,A),D)
Equals(E,1):Copy(Add(A,2),A)
Any(Equals(E,4),Equals(E,8)):Copy(Add(D,E,A),D)
Not(Equals(A,A)):Flag
Not(Equals(A,A)):Copy(Line(3),OLine(E))
Equals(A,A):Move
Any(Equals(E,4),Equals(E,5),Equals(E,6),Equals(E,7),Equals(E,8),Equals(E,9)):Flag
Any(Equals(E,10),Equals(E,11),Equals(E,12),Equals(E,13)):Flag
Start:Copy(1,A)
```

Comment: I can't see a bug, but just in case you should probably use `Modified` condition instead of some of the `Equals`

Comment: [cliqueBot](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37361/31203) looks like it has the same problem. I think it is a compiler bug.

Comment: @MegaTom: The `Modified` condition is an invitation for an infinite loop. If I can't use a parity check, I'll just remove the lines entirely. Figure out something else useful to put in 'em. ;)

Comment: I think I found the bug in the controller. I sent him a pull request. Until he accepts it, you can try my [fork](https://github.com/ctcarton/CodeBots2Java) if you like and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

## sentinel

improvment on `Gard`. Hits nearby bots with flags on the first 8 lines. (that is, all the most used ones)

```
flag
flag
Start:Copy(11,B)
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Mod(E,8)),Line(0))),Not(BotAt(Add(D,1,Mod(E,3))))):If(Equals(OVar(D),Add(D,2)),Line(7),Line(8))
BotAt(Add(D,1)):Copy(Add(D,1),D)
BotAt(Add(D,2)):Copy(Add(D,2),D)
BotAt(Add(D,3)):Copy(Add(D,3),D)
copy(D,OVar(D))
copy(Line(Mod(E,2)),OLine(Mod(E,8)))
Not(Equals(Line(0),Line(1))):copy(Line(Add(9,Mod(E,16))),Line(Mod(E,2)))
```

Comment: I think you have a misplaced bracket on line 3. The first Not isn't closed properly. I think it should be `All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Mod(E,8)),Line(0))),Not(BotAt(Add(D,1,Mod(E,3))))):`

Answer (score 1):

## CliqueBorg

```
Flag
BotAt(D): Copy(Line(Sub(This,1)),OLine(E))
Equals(1,1): Copy(Line(Sub(This,2)),Line(Add(This,Mod(E,21))))
Start: Move
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Sub(OVar(C),1)),Line(3)))):Copy(Line(3),OLine(Sub(OVar(C),1)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(Sub(OVar(C),1)),Cond(3)))):Copy(Cond(3),OCond(Sub(OVar(C),1)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Sub(OVar(C),2)),Line(2)))):Copy(Line(2),OLine(Sub(OVar(C),2)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(Sub(OVar(C),2)),Cond(2)))):Copy(Cond(2),OCond(Sub(OVar(C),2)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Sub(OVar(C),3)),Line(1)))):Copy(Line(1),OLine(Sub(OVar(C),3)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(Sub(OVar(C),3)),Cond(4)))):Copy(Cond(4),OCond(Sub(OVar(C),3)))
```

Trying to combine CliqueBot and Borg technology to create a bot that recognizes copies of itself despite the line offset. It also starts its copying process at the last executed line of code on the opposing bot, rather than line 0, which is more likely to freeze it in place but also more likely to result in a corrupted copy (in fact, I'm not sure this even works, I haven't tested it and it's pretty complex).

Comment: Please replace Plus with Add and Minus with Sub

Answer (score 1):

## Driveby

One last try before the deadline.

```
Flag
Flag
BotAt(D):Copy(Line(Sub(This,1)),OLine(E))
Equals(1,1):Copy(Line(Sub(This,2)),Line(Add(This,Mod(E,21))))
Start:Move
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Sub(OVar(C),1)),Line(3)))):Copy(Line(3),OLine(Sub(OVar(C),1)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(Sub(OVar(C),1)),Cond(3)))):Copy(Cond(3),OCond(Sub(OVar(C),1)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Sub(OVar(C),2)),Line(2)))):Copy(Line(2),OLine(Sub(OVar(C),2)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(Sub(OVar(C),2)),Cond(2)))):Copy(Cond(2),OCond(Sub(OVar(C),2)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OLine(Sub(OVar(C),3)),Line(1)))):Copy(Line(1),OLine(Sub(OVar(C),3)))
All(BotAt(D),Not(Equals(OCond(Sub(OVar(C),3)),Cond(4)))):Copy(Cond(4),OCond(Sub(OVar(C),3)))
BotAt(D):Copy(Add(D,1),D)
Equals(1,1):Move
```